# capitalizing all first letters from a string in a text file in python

Tags: python

```
f = open("text.txt","r")
for x in f:
    capitalized_version = x.capitalize()
    print(capitalized_version)
```

text.txt contains: ***hello my name is***

and it converts it to: ***Hello my name is***

but i want to capitalize all first letters, so ***Hello My Name Is*** from the text.txt and put it in a new file text2.txt

This is my first post on stackoverflow so help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: use [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

Comment: Hi and welcome. I'm sure you already know this, but your first interaction with SO should always be an attempt to find an existing answer, not to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i'll keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `x.title()` instead of `x.capitalize()`. See [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

**OR**

make first letter upper case of all words in the file

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
   the_string = file.read()
   result = re.sub(r'(((?<=\s)|^|-)[a-z])', lambda x: x.group().upper(), the_string)
   print(result)
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/CCJF78043

Answer (score 0):

You have the method [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) that can do it:

```
for x in f:
    capitalized_version = x.title()
    print(capitalized_version)
```

From the docs:

> Return a titlecased version of the string where words start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase.

---

This solution can be buggish with quotes or other special characters. The documentations suggests using regular expressions, if needed:

```
>>> import re
>>> def titlecase(s):
...     return re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
...                   lambda mo: mo.group(0).capitalize(),
...                   s)
...
>>> titlecase("they're bill's friends.")
"They're Bill's Friends."
```